# Getting information from previous row with R following a certain factor

Tags: r, row

I have this sample:

```
> a
   Ship duration.minutes event   Location
1     a               NA enter     Skagen
2     a             1616  trip       <NA>
3     a             4308  stop Copenhagen
4     b             1646  trip       <NA>
5     b             5751  stop     Gdynia
6     b               75  trip       <NA>
7     b            45666  stop     Gdansk
8     c             2531  trip       <NA>
9     c             5360  stop   Szczecin
10    d              287  trip       <NA>
```

I would like to add a new column called "destination", and to add the name of the destination in these cells.

The output would be:

```
> output
   Ship duration.minutes event   Location  Destination
1     a               NA enter     Skagen  NA
2     a             1616  trip       <NA>  Copenhagen
3     a             4308  stop Copenhagen  <NA>
4     b             1646  trip       <NA>  Gdynia
5     b             5751  stop     Gdynia  <NA> 
6     b               75  trip       <NA>  Gdansk
7     b            45666  stop     Gdansk  <NA>
8     c             2531  trip       <NA>  Szczecin
9     c             5360  stop   Szczecin  <NA>
10    d              287  trip       <NA>  <NA>
```

It means that it is working per Ship: it would give the destination for the ship a only. It is taking the next Location after a trip for this very ship.

I tried with `moves <- setDT(a)[, .(from = Location[-.N], to = Location[-1L]) , Ship]` but it does not keep the column `duration.minutes`:

```
> dput(moves)
structure(list(Ship = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c"), from = structure(c(4L, 
NA, NA, 3L, NA, NA), .Label = c("Copenhagen", "Gdansk", "Gdynia", 
"Skagen", "Szczecin"), class = "factor"), to = structure(c(NA, 
1L, 3L, NA, 2L, 5L), .Label = c("Copenhagen", "Gdansk", "Gdynia", 
"Skagen", "Szczecin"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .Names = c("Ship", 
"from", "to"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x00000000003e0788>)
```

It looks like this:

```
> moves
   Ship   from         to
1:    a Skagen       <NA>
2:    a   <NA> Copenhagen
3:    b   <NA>     Gdynia
4:    b Gdynia       <NA>
5:    b   <NA>     Gdansk
6:    c   <NA>   Szczecin
```

The sample of the data called a is:

```
> dput(data)
structure(list(Ship = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "c", 
"c", "d"), duration.minutes = c(NA, 1616L, 4308L, 1646L, 5751L, 
75L, 45666L, 2531L, 5360L, 287L), event = structure(c(1L, 3L, 
2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("enter", "stop", 
"trip"), class = "factor"), Location = structure(c(4L, NA, 1L, 
NA, 3L, NA, 2L, NA, 5L, NA), .Label = c("Copenhagen", "Gdansk", 
"Gdynia", "Skagen", "Szczecin"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Ship", 
"duration.minutes", "event", "Location"), row.names = c(NA, -10L
), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

I am afraid it is hard to work with setDT. Is there a way to keep the column duration.minutes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this covers all of your use cases, but you could use the `lead` function to capture the next value for each `Ship`. It also seems like it makes more sense to have all of the values in a single column, rather than separate `Location` and `Destination` columns.

```
library(tidyverse)              

a %>% 
  group_by(Ship) %>% 
  mutate(Destination = lead(Location),
         Location = coalesce(Location, Destination)) %>% 
  select(-Destination)
```

> ```
>    Ship  duration.minutes event Location  
>    <chr>            <int> <fct> <fct>     
>  1 a                   NA enter Skagen    
>  2 a                 1616 trip  Copenhagen
>  3 a                 4308 stop  Copenhagen
>  4 b                 1646 trip  Gdynia    
>  5 b                 5751 stop  Gdynia    
>  6 b                   75 trip  Gdansk    
>  7 b                45666 stop  Gdansk    
>  8 c                 2531 trip  Szczecin  
>  9 c                 5360 stop  Szczecin  
> 10 d                  287 trip  <NA>
> ```

If you want to keep separate columns, then you can shorten the code to this:

```
a %>% 
  group_by(Ship) %>% 
  mutate(Destination = lead(Location))
```

For the data sample you provided, `fill` can also create a single column in one step:

```
a %>% 
  group_by(Ship) %>% 
  fill(Location, .direction="up")
```

Comment: ´a %>% 
  group_by(Ship) %>% 
  mutate(Destination = lead(Location))´ seems to be working perfectly! Thanks @eipi10!